# Automatically Replace Google Sheet Entries

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet to reference in an app or game engine that will display only the most recent 15 entries. For more context, I created a website with a form that connects to the sheet. And the game will have a variable assigned to the cells of the sheet. For this reason, I'd like to keep the same 15 cells, but have the info in them update and change when new entries are submitted.

So on the 16th entry, the 1st row will automatically be replaced with that info. The 17th entry will replace the 2nd row... the 31st will replace the 1st again, etc.. So I'd like to limit the number of rows to 15 and always be replacing current entries in sequence.

Info the website puts in the sheet:

- date/time submitted (only useful if a method can reference it i.e. the oldest entry to be removed)
- city (the actual info I need for the variable in game)

I'm fairly new to coding and my searches haven't been productive. All help would be much appreciated, even if it's links to longer books or tutorials I may need.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to just have it so new entries always go to the 1st row and "push" the rest down. This would work as a solution and then I could wipe the entire sheet every 200 entries or something. Thanks

Comment: What is the exact name of the form-data intake sheet? And what is the exact range of columns for which you want the 15 round-robin entries returned? Since we can't see your  actual spreadsheet, it will cut out guesswork ( both for those here and for you in trying to apply a formula to your actual sheet) to have these two pieces of information provided.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. There will be 15 rows, and I really only need to reference 1 column. I used squarespace to make a website and their built in "forms" have the option to store the answers in google sheets, it automatically gives a second column with the time of submission, but I don't actually need this info. I don't know what you mean by the exact name of the form-data intake sheet. I tried googling some of that lingo to no avail.. again total noob. My appologies.. maybe the info that its the squarespace built-in tech for form storage helps?

Comment: When you open your Google spreadsheet, the data from the form shows up in a sheet (which some might think of as a "tab"). What is the name of that sheet/tab that holds the incoming data (not the name of the whole spreadsheet, just the individual sheet/tab name within the spreadsheet)? And is the data you want coming into Col A or Col B?

Comment: Ohh gotcha. It's "sheet 1" and Col B. Thanks again for being patient!

Comment: Is the sheet name exactly **sheet 1** (lowercase 's' and a space before the '1'), or is it **Sheet1** (uppercase 'S' and no space before the '1')? And does Row 1 of this sheet have headers, with actual data starting in Row 2? I have to ask because if these things are wrong, the formula will not work as expected or will just return an error. It's always best to get the careful details at the start than to have to overexplain or troubleshoot later.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. It is: Sheet1. Row 1 does have headers, actual data starts in Row 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given your additional comments...

First, add a new sheet (e.g., Sheet2).

In cell A1 of that new sheet, place the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula({Sheet1!B1; QUERY(QUERY({ROW(Sheet1!B2:B),ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(SEQUENCE(15)&"~",ROUNDUP(ROWS(Sheet1!B2:B)/15)),"~",1,1))),ROWS(Sheet1!B2:B),1),Sheet1!B2:B},"Select Col2, Col3 WHERE Col3 Is Not Null ORDER BY Col1 Desc LIMIT 15"),"Select Col2 ORDER BY Col1")})`

`ArrayFormula(...)` means that an entire range will be considered and processed.

The outermost curly brackets `{ }` form a virtual array consisting of your Col-B header and then the results you're after. The semicolon in the virtual array means "Place the next part underneath" (i.e., place the results under the header).

The rest of the formula does "the magic."

It would be very difficult to explain that magic in detail, but in essence, here's what happens.

Virtually, three columns are formed.

- The first contains the `ROW` numbers from Sheet1!B2:B.
- The second contains a repeating `SEQUENCE` of the numbers 1-15. This entire formula section is necessary to form that repeating sequence — `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(SEQUENCE(15)&"~",ROUNDUP(ROWS(B2:B)/15)),"~",1,1))),ROWS(B2:B),1)` — and it functions only within the outer `ArrayFormula(...)` wrap.
- The third contains your actual data from Sheet1!B2:B.

The innermost `QUERY` weeds out all rows of that three-column virtual array where no data yet exists, orders the remaining results in reverse order by row number, strips off that first row-number column (which is then no longer needed) and `LIMIT`s the return to 15 rows.

This now leaves the bottom 15 entries in a two-column array: the first column is those repeating `SEQUENCE` numbers 1-15, starting at whatever cutoff the above `QUERY` left in place. For instance, that order might be:

10, 9, 8, 7 , 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11

The outermost `QUERY` `ORDER`s `BY` those numbers, then strips off that first column of numbers (which is also then no longer needed)...

... leaving just your data in the order requested (at least if I clearly understand your end goal).

Comment: It's working! I can't thank you enough. The idea of adding numbers to track the positions totally makes sense. I didn't know that was possible. Not only will this make the project work, but I learned a lot in the process. Again, thank you! I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer but will when I do.

Comment: Glad it worked as expected. You can still mark the post as "Best Answer" by clicking the checkmark beside it on your end. This alerts the contributor community here that the issue is fully resolved; and it allows future site visitors to most easily find the answer if it pertains to their own current issue.